# What causes post-masturbation guilt?

Tags: emotion, sexuality

Is there a study regarding guilt complex associated with masturbation? 
I am interested to what it can be traced down to. I
wonder what actually happens in the brain before, during, and after the process on a subatomic (for want of a better word) level.

Comment: My first instinct is that it's a result of being shamed about sexuality in their community, family, peer group, etc.

Comment: It could also be due to a certain religious background. But then upbringing does have a  strong hold in it.

Comment: Or perhaps the perception of wastage of time or energy, or the perception of lack of self control

Comment: I guess the question 'may' become redundant if one just accepts one's physical needs. Like eating/drinking or say going to toilet or cleaning nose, one has to  empty one's sperm tank. If one accepts this fact, the guilt 'may' disappear. Of course, besides, one needs to keep oneself busy and do constructive work, so that when one takes break or relieves oneself, it may feel like an earned right.

Comment: I would rather look towards an emotion of reflective level; the process of emotional appraisal may involve individual concerns and past experiences, including cultural background, and social esteem.
At first, the personal concern may be more important than the other values. But once the need is fulfilled, cultural background and social esteem may be more prominent.

Comment: The question is likely too broad to be answered in a useful way